# Moderator cannot ban an administrator (policy)

Tags: laravel

I have a user table with a rank_id and a rank table with each role (admin, modo, premium, user..), so far it's classic.

Then I have a panel for the staff, with a list of users and on each line I have a "ban" button.
I would like that a moderator can't ban the roles above him (admin).
How do I take this into account? Some kind of hierarchy.

I use policies, I wrote that a moderator can ban but not if the target user is with the admin role. It's not very clean and complicated if I had many roles.

I guess there is a more viable solution for that, I thought of putting on each role a kind of "strength" scale, admin would have 1000, moderator would have 800, user would have 100 etc.. But I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said you can put a strength column and give each user some strength points.

And your policy looks like this: 
 
`return auth()->user()->strength > $user->strength;` 

And the logged user can't ban a user with a higher strength.

Comment: I was thinking about a method but in the end it's as simple as that, you are totally right! I'm testing to set this up and will get back to you if needed ;) Otherwise I validate